# Casting an object to a another certain object, then modifying it

Tags: java, reflection

So here's what I'm trying to do. At the beginning of the program, the class looks through all the fields in that class. If the field is a specific type of object, then it adds it to the list. The list of certain objects can be called later on, and modified.

SORRY, forgot to post the actual error. When I try to cast the class to the type Value, I get this error:

```
Cannot cast from Class<capture#8-of ?> to Value<?>
```

Here's the main part:

```
private List<Value> values = new ArrayList<Value>();

for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (f == null)
            continue;
        Class<?> clazz = f.getType();
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(Value.class)) {
            Value<?> value = (Value) clazz;
            values.add(value);
        }
    }
```

Here's the Value class:

```
public class Value<E> {

private String name;
private E value;

public Value(final String name, final E value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
}

public final String getValueName() {
    return name;
}

public final E getValue() {
    return value;
}

public final void setValue(final E newValue) {
    value = newValue;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Sorry, edited OP.

Comment: `List<Value> values` ... why do you use a raw `Value`? On purpose? And what is `list` here `list.add(value);`? A different list than `values`?

Comment: @Tom list was supposed to be the list 'values'. I changed it in OP. And yes, I'm doing it on purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to cast the class or type of the field to Value but thats not what you want to do, you want the value or actual data of the field and cast that.

You can get the value (or data) of a field like this:

```
Value<?> val = (Value<?>) field.get(parent_object);
```

Comment: I tried that, the object val is coming out null every time... Not sure why

Comment: @Devin I do not have that problem with this code                                       `System.out.println(Test.class.getField("hello").get(null));`

Comment: The object val comes out null every time.

Comment: There are no compile-time errors, the but the object val is always null. I "System.out.println(val)" and it prints out null. I try to access methods/variables inside of val and it throws a NPE.

Comment: @Devin Is it throwing any exceptions?

Comment: Could you update your post with the changed code? That would make helping a lot easier.

Comment: There is no updated code, this is how I'm running it.